# How to get a key in a JavaScript object by a value in array?

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `assignments` which assigns students to rooms, e.g.,:
```

```
const assignments = 
  {
     101: ["A","B","C"],
     102: ["D","E","F"],
     103: ["G","H","I"],
  }
```

```

I want an elegant function `find_room(assignments, student)` that will return to me the room assigned for a student. For example `find_room(assignments, "B")` will return `101`.

Comment: Please edit your question and include any attempts you've made of your own. Without them, your question reads as a request for someone to write your code. It's likely to be downvoted and/or vote-closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution

```js
const assignments = 
  {
     101: ["A","B","C"],
     102: ["D","E","F"],
     103: ["G","H","I"],
  }

function find_room(assignments, dude){
    return Object.keys(assignments).find(room=>assignments[room].includes(dude))
}

console.log(find_room(assignments, "B"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function find_room(assignments, student) {
    for(const [room, students] of Object.entries(assignments)) {
      if(students.includes(student)) 
         return room;
    }
}
```

Just iterate over the objects entries and check if the array contains the student, if so return the key.

Comment: This is a good answer, although I can't help but feel that answering these *"Someone just write this code for me"* questions isn't the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

This should be do what you want:

```js
var assignments = 
{
    101: ["A","B","C"],
    102: ["D","E","F"],
    103: ["G","H","I"]
}

function find_room(assignments, student)
{
    for(var roomNumber in assignments)
    {
        if(assignments[roomNumber].indexOf(student) >= 0) 
            return roomNumber;
    }
}

var roomNumber = find_room(assignments, "B");

if(roomNumber != void 0)
    console.log('Student "B" was found in room: ' + roomNumber);
else
    console.log('Student "B" was not found.');
```